# Logging into facebook with python

Tags: python

If I run the following code 10 times in a row, it will work about half the time and fail the rest. Anyone know why?

```
import urllib2, cookielib, re, os, sys

class Facebook():
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        opener.addheaders = [('Referer', 'http://login.facebook.com/login.php'),
                            ('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
                            ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7) Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)')]
        self.opener = opener

    def login(self):
        url = 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1'
        data = "locale=en_US&non_com_login=&email="+self.email+"&pass="+self.password+"&lsd=20TOl"

        usock = self.opener.open('http://www.facebook.com')
        usock = self.opener.open(url, data)
        if "Logout" in usock.read():
            print "Logged in."
        else:
            print "failed login"
            print usock.read()
            sys.exit()

f = Facebook("test@gmail.com", "asdfasdf")
f.login()
```

Comment: what's the error when it fails?

Comment: No error. The login fails. output is "failed login"

Comment: I can't say much about why it's failing, but the error message here is that I "must enable cookies".

Btw, you see nothing after "failed login" because the `usock` was already read. Save the result from `self.opener.open` and print it on error and you'll see the precise error (in html, though).

**EDIT**: Also, why are you opening the url twice?

Comment: The first time I open it is to set the cookie. If you try submitting the post without the cookie set you get teh "Must enable cookies" error.

Answer (score 16):

So I tried your code, and got it to log in once, then like you I had trouble logging in again. On a line before the 'if' statement, I added 
print usock.read()
and ended up getting a bunch of html code. I then dropped that code into a notepad, saved it as an html file, and pulled it up.
This is what's happening: Facebook gets suspicious that we're logging in from a computer program, and is waiting for us to verify that we're real by showing a captcha word. The program doesn't account for this, and prints "Failed login" when it's really more of a pending login.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the same problem. The only solution I found was... that facebook mobile is more stable.

```
class Acc:
    jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
    cookie = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar)       
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie)

    headers = {
        "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; FreeBSD i386; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080609 Firefox/2.0.0.14",
        "Accept" : "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,text/png,*/*;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Language" : "en-us,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Charset" : "ISO-8859-1",
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Host": "m.facebook.com"
    }

    def login(self):
        try:
            params = urllib.urlencode({'email':'test@test.test','pass':'dempassword','login':'Log+In'})
            req = urllib2.Request('http://m.facebook.com/login.php?m=m&refsrc=m.facebook.com%2F', params, self.headers)
            res = self.opener.open(req)
            html = res.read()

            #print res.getheader('location').split('/')[3]

        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print e.msg
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print e.reason[1]
        return False

    def fetch(self,url):
        req = urllib2.Request(url,None,self.headers)
        res = self.opener.open(req)
        return res.read()

bla = Acc()
bla.login()
```

Also, facebook mobile isn't filled up with ajax, so figuring out what requests to make is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The fix worked for me, every time.
Then I wanted to actually read the content of the page after logging in. For this, I added a 'print usock.read()' right after 'print 'Logged in'', but that returned an empty string. I guessed it's because usock is getting called twice, so I just modified the first call to usock:

```
    a = usock.read()
    if "logout" in a:
        print "Logged in."
        return a
```

This way there's only one call to usock, the first time, and it works. Instead of print a, I then used return a, because then I could directly use login() to return the page source. But please suit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Facebook limits the maximum number of login attempts per minute. It's just a guess.

Comment: I thought this initially, but the reason I doubt it is the pattern. It doesnt work a few times then fail all in a row. Its completely random when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: Protip: Facebook does actually block after x attempts. I've run into the same problem

Comment: Additionally, screen scraping of this sort if against their ToS - so don't be suprised if your account disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found the answer by basically looking at the response data.

"Logout" does not exist - at least for me -, yet, "Log out" and "logout" does (the later appears as `logout.php`, which probably won't change on different locales). So, for your particular issue, just replace `"Log out"` with `"logout"` and you're all set.

Now, as to why it was working after the first try, I didn't bother to check

Also, I'd suggest using urllib's [urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#utility-functions) for sending your data to avoid nasty bugs when sending stuff with "&", ";" and other characters used for control. (The "@" from the e-mails should be encoded also, but it doesn't seem to break this particular case)

**Note**: My test was basically changing the string and running it over a loop for some time, no issues were detected. If it does break for you, maybe [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196550/andrey-fedoseev) is right.

Comment: @ Caio Romao how to extarct friendlist and how to post on fb wall after successful login