# lxml error "IOError: Error reading file" when parsing facebook mobile in a python scraper script

Tags: python, linux, facebook, web-scraping, lxml

I use a modified script from [Logging into facebook with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030652/logging-into-facebook-with-python) post :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2 -u
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

facebook_email = "YOUR_MAIL@DOMAIN.TLD"
facebook_passwd = "YOUR_PASSWORD"


import cookielib, urllib2, urllib, time, sys
from lxml import etree

jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
cookie = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar)       
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie)

headers = {
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7",
    "Accept" : "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,text/png,*/*;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Language" : "en-us,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Charset" : "utf-8",
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "m.facebook.com"
}

try:
    params = urllib.urlencode({'email':facebook_email,'pass':facebook_passwd,'login':'Log+In'})
    req = urllib2.Request('http://m.facebook.com/login.php?m=m&refsrc=m.facebook.com%2F', params, headers)
    res = opener.open(req)
    html = res.read()

except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.msg
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e.reason[1]

def fetch(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url,None,headers)
    res = opener.open(req)
    return res.read()

body = unicode(fetch("http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=404284859586659&set=a.355112834503862.104278.354259211255891&type=1"), errors='ignore')
tree = etree.parse(body)
r = tree.xpath('/see_prev')
print r.text
```

When I execute the code, problems appears :

```
$ ./facebook_fetch_coms.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./facebook_fetch_coms_classic_test.py", line 42, in <module>
    tree = etree.parse(body)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2957, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:56230)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1533, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82313)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1562, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82606)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1462, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81645)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1002, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78554)
  File "parser.pxi", line 569, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74498)
  File "parser.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75389)
  File "parser.pxi", line 588, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74691)
IOError: Error reading file '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Facebook</title><meta name="description" content="Facebook helps you connect and share with the people in your life."
```

The goal is first to get the link with `id=see_prev` with `lxml`, then using a while loop to open all comments, to finally fetch all messages in a file. Any help will be very appreciated !

**Edit**:
I use Python 2.7.2 on archlinux x86_64 and lxml 2.3.3.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
tree = etree.parse(body)
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) says that "`source` is a filename or file object containing XML data." You have provided a string, so lxml is taking the text of your HTTP response body as the **name** of the file you wish to open. No such file exists, so you get an `IOError`.

The error message you get even says "Error reading file" and then gives your XML string as the *name of the file it's trying to read,* which is a mighty big hint about what's going on.

You probably want [`etree.XML()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XML), which takes input from a string. Or you could just do `tree = etree.parse(res)` to read directly from the HTTP request into lxml (the result of `opener.open()` is a file-like object, and `etree.parse()` should be perfectly happy to consume it).

Comment: I removed `parse()` in favor of `HTML()` and it works better, thanks.