# IOError passing requests Response.content to lxml.etree.parse()

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following xml on a webpage -

```
<entry>
    <id>1750</id>
    <title>variablename</title>
    <source>
      com.tidalsoft.webclient.tes.dsp.db.datatypes.Variable
    </source>
    <tes:variable>
        <tes:ownername>ownergroup</tes:ownername>
        <tes:productiondate>2015-08-17T00:00:00-0400</tes:productiondate>
        <tes:readonly>N</tes:readonly>
        <tes:publish>N</tes:publish>
        <tes:description>
          Decription Here
        </tes:description>
        <tes:startcalendar>0</tes:startcalendar>
        <tes:ownerid>666</tes:ownerid>
        <tes:type>1</tes:type>
        <tes:lastusermodifiedtime>2015-06-15T15:42:27-0400</tes:lastusermodifiedtime>
        <tes:innervalue>\\share\location</tes:innervalue>
        <tes:calc>N</tes:calc>
        <tes:name>variablename</tes:name>
        <tes:startdate>1899-12-30T00:00:00-0500</tes:startdate>
        <tes:pub>Y</tes:pub>
        <tes:lastvalue>\\share\location</tes:lastvalue>
        <tes:id>1750</tes:id>
        <tes:startdateasstring>18991230000000</tes:startdateasstring>
        <tes:lastchangetime>2015-06-15T15:42:27-0400</tes:lastchangetime>
        <tes:clientcachelastchangetime>2015-08-17T09:56:49-0400</tes:clientcachelastchangetime>
    </tes:variable>
</entry>
```

I'm trying to parse this data. I have a get through requests -

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

but when I try to parse the content I get errors.

```
>>> xmlObject = etree.parse(r.content)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apiTest.py", line 46, in <module>
    xmlObject = etree.parse(r.content)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3310, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:7
2517)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etre
e.c:105979)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1817, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lx
ml.etree.c:106278)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1721, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.e
tree.c:105277)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1122, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src
\lxml\lxml.etree.c:100227)
  File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDo
c (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:94350)
  File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.e
tree.c:95786)
  File "parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etr
ee.c:94818)
IOError: Error reading file ''
```

On the last line what is between the quotes is the xml stated at the beginning as a string -

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="ye
s"?><entry xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#"><id>1750</id><title>....`

The data is being provided as content-type: text/xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`etree.parse` expects a filename, a file-like object, or a URL as its first argument (see `help(etree.parse)`). It does not expect an XML string. To parse an XML string use

```
xmlObject = etree.fromstring(r.content)
```

Note that `etree.fromstring` returns a `lxml.etree._Element`. In contrast, `etree.parse` returns a `lxml.etree._ElementTree`. Given the `_Element`, you can obtain the `_ElementTree` with the `getroottree` method:

```
xmlTree = xmlObject.getroottree()
```

Comment: This is one of those places where I wonder if it'd be better to close-as-typo on the question, or at least suggest some major edits to the question title; this isn't likely to help anyone who comes in with XML namespace issues.

Comment: The value of questions like this might lie more in the error message than the question title. If googling `"lxml IOError: Error reading file"` takes you to this page, then it might be a useful question for others. However, when I googled that string, I found this question has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9593990/190597

Comment: Hmm. I regret wasting my close vote on the "typo / unlikely to help others" reason rather than marking as dupe.