# Python code to delete photos/albums from facebook account.

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to build a python program that deletes all the photos from my facebook account. Later on, I might want to extend the code to delete all my friends.

I read about OAuth, graph databases and have a vague idea about the facebook api.

I tried this: [Logging into facebook with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030652/logging-into-facebook-with-python).
to login. But it isn't working for some reason. And I am not sure if that is the right way to do it for my requirements.

Can anyone help me kickstart in the right direction?

Thanks and apologies if I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ty use SDK http://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-sdk to log in. 
Then you can use DELETE HTTP method to remove objects you need. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for more