# Scope of Facebook's Graph API search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, web-crawler

I am using the Facebook Graph API through the Javascript SDK to search for users. However, when I try to find a user that has a protected profile it does not show up in the search results. Which I find weird because if I use the Facebook website to look for the same user using the default search bar, the user DOES show up. Is there any solution to find a user in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific? How do you search for the users, what users are you searching for? As a general rule, if you need something more than basic information provided by Graph API, you will need user's permissions (as in getting their e-mail address and so on).

Comment: I am sorry, i am using the the search function from the graph api through the javascript sdk which looks like this:

`FB.api('/search?q=' + escape('full name') + '&type=user', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});`

So i am looking for users i know the full name of but aren't friends on facebook. The problem I face is that i get different results in using the Graph API search call versus a search query on the normal facebook page, while both logged in with the same user. For a project for my endstudy I need to provide at least the same result as a manual search on facebook would

Comment: Solved by using
!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030652/logging-into-facebook-with-python